# how to draw on an image added in the JLabel on java swing?

Tags: java, image, swing, awt

I want to draw lines that go from (0,0) of the image step of the JFrame to the middle of the image using `g.drawline(x1,y1,x2,y2)`
I tried many things but I couldn't find the solution.
`getX()` and `getY()` are the coordinates relative to the frame, but I want the coordinates relative to the JLabel, to the JFrame.

I want when I resize my image that it remains as such, i.e. which keeps the (0,0) of the image

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Créer une image
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(400, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        // Récupérer le Graphics de l'image pour dessiner
        Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.drawString("Cliquez pour afficher les coordonnées", 100, 200);
        g2d.dispose();

        // Créer un JLabel avec l'image
        JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));

        // Ajouter un écouteur de clic sur l'image
        imageLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();

                System.out.println("Coordonnées dans l'image : " + x + ", " + y);
            }
        });

        // Créer un JPanel pour contenir le JLabel
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(imageLabel);

        // Créer un JFrame pour afficher le JPanel
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `MouseEvent` will give you relative coordinates to the component that the listener is attached to, so, in your context, `0x0` will actally be the top/left position of the label

Comment: @MadProgrammer the problem is that when I click on the top left of the image, I have as coordinates 0x~250

Comment: Well, based on your code, it should be working and it works when I run your code, so you're probably adding the `MouseListener` to the wrong component

Comment: @MadProgrammer i want 0x0 not 0x250 when I point to the top left of the image

Comment: @MadProgrammer maximize the window and try again

Comment: I know what you want, and I'm telling you, based on the code you've provided, `0x0` WILL be the top left of label position - how ever, it may not be the top/left of the icon, as the icon may be draw in a different position within the context of the label - to be honest, this is not the approach I would take to solve this problem

Comment: *"maximize the window and try again"* - It won't make any difference, the `MouseListener` will ALWAYS report the mouse coordinates within the context of the component

Comment: @MadProgrammer you're right ! it works here, but when i put an image on JLabel, it does'nt work

Comment: Use a jpanel to paint on not jlabel, simply explicitly setSize of the jpanel, and always paint the panel with image lines off the buffeted image from the panels 0 0 by getting the graphics object from the panel you paint. Also set the JPanels layout to explicitly not take up space on its borders, I don't know if that last is actually possible on a jlabel, so a panel is what you must use to keep or properly know the component 0 0 coords.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant ok thanks ! I will use a JPanel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MouseListener` will convert the `MouseEvent` coordinates to be relative to the component it is registered to.  This means that when you register the `MouseListener` to the `JLabel`, all the coordinates for the `MouseEvent`s will be relative to it (ie `0x0` will be the top left of the `JLabel`).

However, remember that you don't control the position of the icon and the label may render the icon in a different location. So, when it "appears" to be `0x0`, it may be offset

[image]
[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {
        private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(400, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        public TestPane() {
            // Récupérer le Graphics de l'image pour dessiner
            Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.drawString("Cliquez pour afficher les coordonnées", 100, 200);
            g2d.dispose();

            // Créer un JLabel avec l'image
            JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));

            // Ajouter un écouteur de clic sur l'image
            imageLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                private Point startPoint;

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    Point point = e.getPoint();
                    Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
                    g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
                    g2d.drawString(point.x + "x" + point.y, point.x, point.y + fm.getAscent());
                    g2d.dispose();
                    
                    if (startPoint == null) {
                        startPoint = point;
                    } else {
                        g2d = image.createGraphics();
                        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(startPoint, point));
                        g2d.dispose();
                        startPoint = null;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });

            add(imageLabel);
        }

    }
}
```

## A better approach...

Would be not to use a `JLabel` and take control of the rendering of the image, so you can control the position of the image - or at least have some way to actually determine the position of the image if you align within the component.

To this end, I'd just follow a basic custom painting route and paint the image directly to something like a `JPanel`, for example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new BetterPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class BetterPane extends JPanel {
        private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(400, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        public BetterPane() {
            // Récupérer le Graphics de l'image pour dessiner
            Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.drawString("Cliquez pour afficher les coordonnées", 100, 200);
            g2d.dispose();

            // Ajouter un écouteur de clic sur l'image
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                private Point startPoint;

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    Point point = e.getPoint();
                    Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
                    g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
                    g2d.drawString(point.x + "x" + point.y, point.x, point.y + fm.getAscent());
                    g2d.dispose();
                    if (startPoint == null) {
                        startPoint = point;
                    } else {
                        g2d = image.createGraphics();
                        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(startPoint, point));
                        g2d.dispose();
                        startPoint = null;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }

    }
}
```